# How to configure Bamboo such that it pulls automatically the dependent jars from a local repository that is in SVN?

Tags: svn, maven, repository, local, bamboo

I have configured maven with Bamboo and have a local repository that contains organization specific jars. These jars are stored in SVN. The problem is that when ever I add a jar to the repository (in SVN) and add the dependency to pom xml, Maven does not check it out from SVN. Have a clean build goal configured in Bamboo. What configuration setting am I missing? Help appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing JARs in repository even though your project is built using maven? Does this mean every developer, after checking-out JAR from SVN (along source files) has to manually add it to his local repository?

In most configurations I have seen so far Bamboo was using company-wide Nexus repository, the same as the one that was used by all developers. This way every JAR added to this repository was available to both Bamboo builds and team members.

Each time we need to add some 3rd party/company specific JAR, we simply added it to Nexus before committing the code to make sure neither Bamboo nor other developers' build won't fail.

Comment: Hey Tomasz, thanks for the reply!
The developer doesn't need to manually add it local repository. It is configured in parent pom such way that it'll look for this Checked out maven project that contains jars. Maven does the rest to copy the jars to local repository. BTW I'll check out Nexus repository.